# Using this.template.querySelectorAll() to modify the DOM in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, dom

Currently, I am stuck in a situation to modify the DOM in LWC using the **querySelectorAll** function.

Here the {team.item.Description__c} field having the DOM details and saved in string form into the salesforce database.

team.html

```
<template if:true={teamRecords} >
    <template for:each={teamRecords} for:item="team" for:index="index">
        <div class="descArea" lwc:dom="manual" key={team.item.id}> </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

team.js

```
this.teamRecords.map((item, index) => {
    this.template.querySelectorAll('.descArea').forEach(element => {
        element.innerHTML = item.item.Description__c; //Contains HTML elements
    });
})
```

The .descArea is a class name of a div inside a loop in LWC component and I want to change the content of the div using the **querySelectorAll** function.

Comment: During which stage of the lifecycle are you trying to access the DOM elements?

Comment: Can you please specify what's not working? Isn't the `querySelectorAll` call returning the divs? Or is the HTML not displaying correctly?

Comment: @muenzpraeger I want to add some HTML element which is stored into item.item.Description__c property into the div with class name "descArea".

Comment: Understood. Your question looks like you're having issues with `querySelectorAll`, because it's all *bold*.

Comment: Yes, I want to select all the Div elements and then add some more elements into it.

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear to me why you need to do this imperatively. Would the following accomplish the same thing?

```html
<template if:true={teamRecords} >
    <template for:each={teamRecords} for:item="team" for:index="index">
        <div key={team.item.id}>
            {team.item.Description__c}
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with more details related to {team.item.Description__c} field, which I want to show on the LWC.

Comment: Because what if I want to dynamically make changes to the Shadow DOM?